# Div containing input disapears on mouseout

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep a div visible while the mouse is in the bounds of the div, the code works until it hovers over the input. I would like a sign up form appear `onmouseover` and when the sign in is complete  and the mouse moves off the div is no longer visible. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xhb532v/)

HTML

```
<div class="members">
    <a href="#" id="signUp" class="box">Members</a>
    <div id="sign-up-form" class="sign-up-form">
        <input type="text" name="firstName">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var signUp = document.getElementById('signUp');
var signUpForm = document.getElementById('sign-up-form');

signUp.onmouseover = function(){    
    signUpForm.style.display = 'block';
}
signUpForm.onmouseout = function(){
    signUpForm.style.display = 'none';
}
```

CSS

```
#signUp{
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px;
}

#sign-up-form{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0,83,159,0.6);
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS 'hover' selector?

Comment: While not entirely identical, I would opt for the `:hover` on `div.members` any day. Presentation should not be in JS.

Comment: Although I agree it should be done in css, http://jsfiddle.net/9xhb532v/2/ this isnt a solution just a thought really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this only with CSS:

```
#sign-up-form {
    display: none;
}

.members:hover #sign-up-form {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Only issue is the gap in the CSS between member block and the form. You are going to have the same issue as the OPs original code without a slight adjustment to the positioning.

Comment: thats what happens with css you hover over sign up button and the form shows then you move to fill form and the hover has gone! I can see @Etiennemiret

Comment: Because there is a one pixel gap. If `top: 32px;` is reduced by one pixel, it will work fine.

Comment: @epascarello indeed. I didn’t notice that the form was absolutely positioned until you mentioned it. Which is all what this issue is about. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses mouseover and mouseout event listeners and a function that will listen to all children elements before changing the display of the signUpForm element.

```
function outVis(event) {
        var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
        if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
           return;
        }
    signUpForm.style.display = 'none';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xhb532v/1/